# Any Firefox, Chrome hybrid extensions?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Are there any extensions that are hybrid on both Firefox and Chrome platform? I am porting my extension from Firefox to Chrome and I would like some code examples.

Of course the code base must not be too tiny, and the different builds should share most of the components and are within a same code base. I am not looking for ad blockers that use different code base.

The extension I am working on is currently available both on Firefox and Chrome, but at Chrome there are still some issues. FYI: http://code.google.com/p/foxtrick/

Comment: Check out AdBlock Plus, its on both. I dont know if both branches are developed by the same group tho. :p

Comment: @Drknezz, they are developed by different parties. In fact, they don't even share the same name.

Comment: Oh, discard my message then. Sorry :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out WikiTrail.
The guy even wrote an article on how to develop for both browsers at the same time: 
http://blog.zetabee.com/developing-extensions-for-chrome-vs-firefox

This is sentence from the article:

> The simplicity of Chrome is definitely preferable to the slightly steeper learning curve for Firefox extensions, however as long as you build your extension using mostly HTML/CSS/JS, there isn't much difference between the two browsers.